# Getting Posts for users based on foreign PostLikes

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having trouble performing an idiomatic join with SQLAlchemys DSL. I want to get all the posts that a particular user has 'liked', but I can't seem to get the list of posts.

### Models

#### Post Model

```
class Post(SearchableMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))

    likes = db.relationship('PostLike', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Post {}>".format(self.body)
```

#### PostLike Model

```
class PostLike(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post_like'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

#### User Model

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    posts = db.relationship("Post", backref="author", lazy="dynamic")
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    location = db.Column(db.String(100))
    is_private = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    mailbox_enabled = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

### What I've tried

```
user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    
# this gets the posts likes successfully
liked_posts = user.liked.order_by(PostLike.timestamp.desc())

# This is where I attempt the join - not working
new_posts = Post.query.join(
    "liked_posts", Post.id == liked_posts
)

print(new_posts)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add the code of your `User` model?

Comment: Thanks :-D I have added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `secondary` attribute of the `relationship` function, it allow to define many-to-many relations:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    # Some columns and relationships here
    liked_posts = db.relationship("Post", secondary="post_like", backref="users_liked")
```

With that you will be able to access list of `Post` objects liked by user:

```
liked_posts = user.liked_posts
```

More on [many-to-many and other types of relations](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) in the SQLAlchemy documentation (it supports some very unusual combinations).